# Как в QT5 в QTableWidget из делегата изменить значение в ячейке из другой колонки?

Tags: c++, qt5

Задача следующая: ComboBoxDelegate задает точность и шаг приращения в другой колонке той же строки, но с DoubleSpinBoxDelegate. 
Проблема в том, что если изменить точность в более грубую сторону, то значение в ячейках из других колонок той же строки надо автоматически округлить. 
Например есть значение 29.99999 при точности 0.00001, изменили точность до 0.0001 и значение автоматически должно стать 29.99990 (значение 30 - это уже за пределами диапазона).
Ниже приведен метод делегата:

```
void ComboBoxStepFreqDelegate::setEditorData( QWidget * editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
int value = index.model()->data( index, Qt::EditRole ).toInt();
QComboBox * cb = static_cast<QComboBox*>( editor );

int idx = cb->findData( value );
if ( idx < 0 ) return;
cb->setCurrentIndex( idx );

int tmp = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();
int shift;
switch (tmp)
    {
    case step10:
        shift = 100000;
        break;
    case step100:
        shift = 10000;
        break;
    default:
        shift = 1000000;
    }
QModelIndex tFreqIndex = index.sibling(index.row(), FREQ_TX);
QModelIndex rFreqIndex = index.sibling(index.row(), FREQ_RX);
double valt = tFreqIndex.model()->data(tFreqIndex, Qt::DisplayRole).toDouble();
double valr = rFreqIndex.model()->data(rFreqIndex, Qt::DisplayRole).toDouble();
valt = floor(valt * shift) / shift;
valr = floor(valr * shift) / shift;
// --- эти две строки выдают ошибку компиляции ---
tFreqIndex.model()->setData(tFreqIndex, valt, Qt::EditRole);
rFreqIndex.model()->setData(rFreqIndex, valr, Qt::EditRole);
//------------------------------------------------
}
```

Вопрос - как записать сформированные данные в ячейки, поскольку я пока не разобрался?

Comment: `index.model()->setData(...` ?

Comment: bool setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int Role = Qt::EditRole ); Конечно, третий параметр можно опустить, но не в этом суть.

Comment: по идеи, если вы в index укажите индекс другой ячейки и значение, получится. Возможно, с `Role` понадобится поиграться

Comment: Да уже с утра играюсь - пока не вышло

Comment: Что, ничего не меняется?

Comment: Увы, пока ничего.

Comment: Неужели никто не знает ?!...